# How to create a autorun file in linux and execute a shell file?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, redhat, autorun

How to create a autorun file in linux which is similar to autorun.inf in Windows in order to execute a shell file ie Following are the requirment

1.Autorun the installer file ./example.sh

When CD is mounted onto the system .

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: The main issue is this: Linux doesn't have an "autorun" system installed by default (which is IMO a Good Thing). There is an `autorun` program that can be installed, though: http://linux.die.net/man/1/autorun

Comment: @tommieb: I read it as being in a "make an installation disk" context and thus acceptable for Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 3):

this is not possible. would be too much of a risk. You can of course do this for your own system in various variants. for example cronjobs. but i suppose you want it to run on any other system...

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1 in Linux's Security: Any new Executable file come to system haven't the due to execute himself without permission from his user/owner :)
you can make an autorun for your system but for other systems nop I guess

Answer (score 0):

we might use our udev rules :

```
mount /mnt/flash && sh /mnt/flash/autorun.sh
```

with proper device signature (product id, device id).

or

use "autorun" command, which currently works with cdrom.